# How to get nearest coordinates from database in mysql?

Tags: mysql, distance

I have got a table with id,latitude (lat),longitude (lng),altitude (alt).
I have some coordinates and I would like to find the closest entry in the DB.
I used this but not yet working correctly:

```
SELECT lat,ABS(lat - TestCordLat), lng, ABS(lng - TestCordLng), alt AS distance
FROM dhm200
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 6
```

I have a table with the 6 nearest points displaying me the lattitude, longtitude and altitude.

Comment: It looks like you're ordering by altitude, which you've named as distance for some reason. I assume when you say 'it isn't working correctly' the results aren't close to the test coordinates you're using?

Comment: when I remove "alt" I get a better (right?) result but I like to get "alt" in the result of the querry...

Comment: Why are you using `alt AS distance` - while at the same time computing `ABS(lat-TestCordLat)` and `ABS(lng-TestCordLng)` but not using them?

Comment: You should order by the two ABS values instead of the altitude, that'll give you closer matches.

Comment: like this?

`SELECT lat, lng, alt, ABS(lat - TestCordLat), ABS(lng - TestCordLng)
FROM dhm200
ORDER BY ABS(lat - TestCordLat) and ABS(lng - TestCordLng) ASC 
LIMIT 6`

Comment: If the differences in longitude and latitude are much greater than the differences in altitude (which they would be in many geographical applications), then using the altitude information would be redundant. What kind of geographical distances and altitudes are likely to be considered?

Comment: I have a huge DB with altitude values and their coordinates. now I like to ask the DB to give me the closest altitude to the coordinate I query.

Comment: That doesn't clarify things (and doesn't make sense actually). The reason I ask is because the most suitable algorithm to use will depend on the distance scales involved. Over medium distance scales (a few hundreds of miles), you might be able to use a linear approximation to the earth's surface - significantly reducing the number of trigonometric functions you need to use.

Comment: yes its definitely close distance within 200m

Comment: And the altitudes?

Comment: same, the approximation can be used. Should I scan the DB for the closest North coordinate within 0.01° and then use this data to calculate the distance to their east coordinate?

Comment: You will need to convert the differences in longitudes and latitudes (in degrees) to actual distances (in metres or kilometres) and then compute the Euclidean distance.

Comment: What shape is your planet?

Comment: While it's not an answer to your specific question I would suggest that you consider PostGIS (which is a geo-special information system built over PostgreSQL).  http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/knn.html ... here's how you'd find nearest neighbors using that system.

Under MySQL I'd recommend creating and maintaining a table of pairwise points, computing the distances in an application and using JOINs to access any data in terms of those distances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the [Haversine](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/mysql-calculating-distance-based-on-latitude-and-longitude.html) formula to calculate distances taking into account the latitude and longitude:

```
dlon = lon2 - lon1 
 dlat = lat2 - lat1 
 a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2 
 c = 2 * atan2( sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a) ) 
 distance = R * c (where R is the radius of the Earth)
```

However, the altitude raises the difficulty of the problem. If between point A and point B, having different altitudes the road contains a lot of high altitude differences, then assuming that the altitude's line's derivative between the two points is unchanged might be misleading, not taking that into account at all might be very misleading. Compare the distance between a point in China and a point in India, having the Himalaja in between with the distance between two points on the surface of the Pacific ocean. A possibility would be to vary R to be the average of the altitudes for each comparisons, but in case of large distances this could be misleading, as discussed earlier.

Comment: @Andy you are welcome. If this answer helped you solve your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Query to get nearest distance in `kilometer (km)` from mysql:

```
SELECT id, latitude, longitude, SQRT( POW(69.1 * (latitude - 4.66455174) , 2) + POW(69.1 * (-74.07867091 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3) , 2)) AS distance FROM ranks ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

You may wish to limit radius by `HAVING` syntax.

```
... AS distance FROM ranks HAVING distance < '150' ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

Example:

```
mysql> describe ranks;
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int           | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| latitude   | decimal(10,8) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| longitude  | decimal(11,8) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id, latitude, longitude, SQRT( POW(69.1 * (latitude - 4.66455174) , 2) + POW(69.1 * (-74.07867091 - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3) , 2)) AS distance FROM ranks ORDER BY distance ASC;
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
| id | latitude    | longitude    | distance           |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
|  4 |  4.66455174 | -74.07867091 |                  0 |
| 10 |  4.13510880 | -73.63690401 |  47.59647003096195 |
| 11 |  6.55526689 | -73.13373892 | 145.86590936973073 |
|  5 |  6.24478548 | -75.57050110 | 149.74731096011348 |
|  7 |  7.06125013 | -73.84928550 | 166.35723903407165 |
|  9 |  3.48835279 | -76.51532198 | 186.68173882319724 |
|  8 |  7.88475514 | -72.49432589 | 247.53456848808233 |
|  1 | 60.00001000 | 101.00001000 |  7156.836171031409 |
|  3 | 60.00001000 | 101.00001000 |  7156.836171031409 |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```